# DICOM Image viewer for Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, images

In case you were wondering DICOM (Digital Imaging and Communications in Medicine) is a set of standards in medical imaging. I have a CT result saved conforming to that standard and I want to be able to see the scans.

The directory structure looks like this:

```
123456 (folder)
|- 2342345 (file)
|- 2342346 (file)
|- 2342347 (file)
|- [...] (more files)
DICOMDIR (file)
```

A Google search showed a lot of results for *DICOM viewer* and I even tried one but it only shows the thumbnails of the images. Could anyone recommend a good viewer so I don't have to try them all? Maybe with export functionality.

Thank you,
Alin

Comment: Have you tried Irfanview or something like that?

Comment: I tried Paint.NET and renaming to jpeg, png, gif and bmp. It didn't work. Those aren't normal images with different extensions. Also at this moment I found (at the 3rd try) an app that works decently, called MicroDicom, but I'm still waiting for answers. Maybe someone has more knowledge to share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good viewer is DICOMan (<strike>http://www.radonc.uams.edu/DICOMan.asp</strike> http://radonc.uams.edu/research/dicoman/) but IrfanView shall also be sufficiant for your needs, since it is free. Did you install the plugins? http://irfanview.tuwien.ac.at/plugins/irfanview_plugins_427_setup.exe

Comment: the dicoman link yields a 404

Comment: added a link to DICOMan that worked as of 10 Sept 12.

Answer (score 1):

microdicom worked for me:

> MicroDicom is application for primary processing and preservation of
>   medical images in DICOM format It is equipped with most common tools
>   for manipulation of DICOM images and it has an intuitive user
>   interface.  It also has the advantage of being free for use and
>   accessible to everyone.

http://www.microdicom.com/

Answer (score 1):

The freely downloadable tool [TomoVision](http://www.tomovision.com/products/tomovision.html) will work as a DICOM viewer. No installation needed, it's just a single `.exe`.

It is normally meant as a viewer for about 50 non-DICOM, proprietary medical imaging formats, which can then be converted to DICOM with [DICOMatic](http://www.tomovision.com/products/dicomatic.html). However, it can also read DICOM as per its [list of supported formats](http://www.tomovision.com/products/format_image.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a GUI that looks like what physicians are used to, you may want to have a look at:

- http://ginkgo-cadx.com/en/
- http://www.cti.gov.br/invesalius/